# Does INotifyPropertyChanged require invoke in all properties

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a model

```
    private List<POStatusModel> _postatuslist;
    public List<POStatusModel> PoStatusList
    {
        set
        {
            _postatuslist = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("PoStatusList"));
        }
        get { return _postatuslist; }
    }

    public class POStatusModel
    {
        public int pocount { set; get; }
        public string postatus { set; get; }
        public DateTime timestamp { set; get; }
        public System.Windows.Media.Brush brushColor { set; get; }
        public POStatusModel()
        { }

    }
```

Which is bound to the items control

```
        <ItemsControl Name="PoStatusItemsControl" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,2,2,0" ItemsSource="{Binding PoStatus.PoStatusList}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding brushColor}">
                    <Run Text="{Binding pocount}"></Run>
                    <Run Text="-"></Run>
                    <Run Text="{Binding postatus}"></Run>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
     </ItemsControl>
```

Once in a while the list refreshes and different data may appear. But it doesn't change. Even though the invoke gets raised.

This is how i update the list int he view model

```
   public MetricPoStatusModel PoStatus { get; set; }
```

and under timer it does this

PoStatus = new MetricPoStatusModel(Connection);

Should i be doing propertychanged invoke for elements under the PoStatus model class as well?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use `RaisePropertyChanged("PropertyName")` then in your binding use `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` in your itemsource binding.

Comment: It only requires `RaisePropertyChanged` if you want to update a property in your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do not use lists but ObservableCollection which already implement stuff related to notification. When you add a new item to the collection, It will be added automatically to the control
2. You use INotifyProperty changed on classes you want to be represented by controls and which will trigger a UI update when the data updates. So if you would like the timestamp  from POStatusModel to be shown and updated, POStatusModel would need to implement the interface
3. Do not, ever, includeUI stuff into your VieModel, like you did with the brush. You can include a string that represents a name, and with a binding definition you would define a, so called, converter. It is a class that gets in between the data and the UI element. If you store in the VM's string a color name "red" and the VM is bound to a control, then the converter you define would take the string and try to turn it into the color object it requires. Sounds like a small overhead, but it is actually really usefull and amazing. Once you gather a collection of about 20-30 converters, your productivity will rocket sky high, esspecialy once you discover parameters to the converters
4. Use [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged/wiki/Attributes), It will really save you a ton of time.
5. You will never need to use custom properties to show you a custom formating of a date, you can specify the format in XAML

I did not go too deep into details, but using the basic buzwords, you should be able to find a ton of resource on google.

Comment: if he's not, he should. since he's using lists, its save to assume, he does not even know the details, .... in any case he should investigate it

Comment: Never seen Fody before. I just made a resharper live template so I can type propn and it writes the stuff for me. Interesting though.

Comment: It's not only about speed and code that Resharper can snippet in. It work the other way around. By default all properties become automatically notifiers, except the ones you exclude. Very often your VMs will look like DTOs. This will give you a better overview of your newly clean code.

Comment: Another very nice feature is that sometimes you will have notification properties that are containing two properties, like first Name and LastName stored as string and the FullName returned from a concat. Fody gives you the possibility to specify, either for the FullName to be raised when firstname or lastname change, or .... Specify to the Firstname to also udate for Fullname.

Comment: Very often you will come across scenarios like this and a baseVM class (that everyone has) becomes very big and overcomplicated. This significatly reduces the amount of code

Answer (score 2):

WPF sense changes by INotifyPropertyChanged and IObservableCollection,
So every where you want , your view detect changes you need to implement these interfaces.
for example if you want add an item to PoStatusList you need to use ObservableCollection and if you set your list (PoStatusList) by new list so you need to invoke your NotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: I like the observablecollection option. My issue was that updating it within a background worker, it caused the problem in the dispatch thread. Once I  started notifying the properties change of inner class, everything started to update in the UI.  I also like the idea of brushes converters and give it a spin. Thank you for your help. I will also play around some more with observable collection.

Answer (score 1):

ObservableCollection should be used instead of lists; unless the list is static.

Using an ObservableCollection does not require use of INotifyPropertyChanged.

Once created the ObservableCollection should not be reassigned to a new list, i.e. if you want to repopulate it use Clear() then Add the entries